# Lost WM_NOTIFY from List View control

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a C++/Win32 application with List View control. When the application is started and controls are initialized it receives WM_NOTIFY if the item is selected or changed in List View.

But after opening another window from menu (for instance, "Open file" dialog) the WM_NOTIFY is lost - no notifications received in MainDialog::DialogProc().

Any suggestions how to restore input from List View?

Comment: Sounds like a *code* problem to me. Can we see what we're trying to debug?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460725) to find which window messages List View generates and whether they passed to the parent window.